# How do I link pages in GitHub Pages

Tags: html, hyperlink, github-pages, multipage

Essentially I am trying to link to my my GitHub Pages index.html file to the other files in the repository to make a multi page website.

The URL is correct, I have tried a bunch of ways and I am simply getting no where.
The main branch is called home, in it is the index.html file, as well as the other files, see below:

[Main Branch is called home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYufb.jpg)

The links inside the html file are:

```
<li class="masthead__menu-item">
          <a href="https://xxx.github.io/home/research/">Research</a>
        </li>
```

The file "research" is inside the home branch. I have tried naming it "research.html" I have tried deleteing the "home" from the above link so it directly links to research, see below:

```
<li class="masthead__menu-item">
          <a href="https://xxx.github.io/research/">Research</a>
        </li>
```

Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot and the html you provided, I don't see any *.html extensions following the name of the files you're trying to link to.

For example: try renaming the file "research" to "research.html"

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I tried what you suggested and it still didnt work.

Answer (score 7):

After hours and hours of trying things, I finally got it to work:

```
       <li class="masthead__menu-item">
          <a href="xxx.github.io/research.html">Research</a>
        </li>
```

What I did was to get rid of the "home" and make the page an html file.
Thank you iamabdm and minwka!

Comment: Glad, your problem is solved. Therefore 'xxx.github.io' must be your custom subdomain.

Comment: Yes, such noob and silly mistake, but I reached out to you guys and it shook something in the old neurons. It finally worked! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a html file then the problem is with the address of the URL i.e. `https://xxx.github.io/research/` in `<a href="https://xxx.github.io/research/">Research</a>`.
**The last slash is causing the problem. Remove the last slash from the address, i.e. `https://xxx.github.io/research` and it will be `<a href="https://xxx.github.io/research">Research</a>`.**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your insight. I did what you said and it still didn't work.